# Laravel Bulk Detach

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent-relationship

First, I use `detach()` in laravel with this approach and this is work!

```
$student = \App\StudentRegistrars::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
$student->father_registrars()->detach();
$student->mother_registrars()->detach();
```

But when I am trying to mass detach in laravel, I can't do that.

```
$students = \App\StudentRegistrars::whereIn('id', $ids);
$student->father_registrars()->detach();
$student->mother_registrars()->detach();
```

Any solution about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few issues with your code. You're close, but not quite there.

First, you need to be aware of what your variable is. Currently, this is not working, as `$student` is not defined. You called your variable `$students` (with an 's'), so make sure you're using the right variable.

Secondly, at the point you're calling `detach()`, your `$students` variable is an instance of the `Builder` class, not a single `StudentRegistrars` instance. You need to finalize your query with a `closure`:

```
$students = \App\StudentRegistrars::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Thirdly, the `detach()` method only works on a single instance, so if you called `$students->father_registrars()->detach()`, it would still fail.

You need to iterate your results and call `detach()` one-by-one:

```
foreach ($students as $student) {
  $student->father_registrars()->detach();
  $student->mother_registrars()->detach(); 
}
```

You final code would therefore be:

```
$students = \App\StudentRegistrars::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
foreach ($students as $student) {
  $student->father_registrars()->detach();
  $student->mother_registrars()->detach(); 
}
```

There are more efficient approaches to mass detachment, such as directly querying and deleting records from the pivot table (or tables):

```
DB::table('pivot')->whereIn('column', $ids)->delete();
```

But this answer serves to fix your logic issues.

Comment: I've used foreach back then but I forgot to use get(). That's work! Thanks man!

Comment: Hi man, can you please answer my another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607253/laravel-count-multiple-selected-data-who-has-relationship