# Detach role from the user and delete the user in bulk along with livewire traits

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

#### Description

I have a "belongsToMany" eloquent relationship between users and roles . I am creating a CRUD system with capability to do bulk actions. I followed the Livewire Screencasts [Bulk Export/Delete](https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s7-bulk-actions) and [Refactoring For Re-Usability](https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s7-refactoring). I have created a trait for the bulk actions, so I'm able to use it out of the box.

I need to detach the role from the user and then delete the user in bulk. I am unable to call `roles` relationship on a public method property and detach the same. This is how I detach the role for a single user `$this->user->roles()->detach();` but I'm unable to do it with `$this->selectedRowsQuery->roles()->detach();` in case of bulk user deletion.

#### Stripped-down, copy-pastable code snippets

- Livewire/Backend/UserController

```
public $showUserBulkDeletionModal = false;

public function confirmDeleteBulk()
{
    $deleteCount = $this->selectedRowsQuery->count();
        
    $this->selectedRowsQuery->roles()->detach();
    $this->selectedRowsQuery->delete();
    $this->showUserBulkDeletionModal = false;

    $this->notify('You\'ve deleted '.$deleteCount.' users');
}

public function getRowsQueryProperty()
{
    $query = User::query()
        ->when($this->filters['email'], fn($query, $email) => $query->where('email', 'like', '%'.$email.'%'))
        ->when($this->filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query->whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->where('id', $role)))
        ->when($this->filters['search'], fn($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%'))
        ->when($this->filters['date-min'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)))
        ->when($this->filters['date-max'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)));
        
    return $this->applySorting($query);
}
```

- Livewire/Traits/WithBulkActions

```
trait WithBulkActions
{
    public $selectPage = false;
    public $selectAll = false;
    public $selected = [];

    public function renderingWithBulkActions()
    {
        if ($this->selectAll) $this->selectPageRows();
    }

    public function updatedSelected()
    {
        $this->selectAll = false;
        $this->selectPage = false;
    }

    public function updatedSelectPage($value)
    {
        if ($value) return $this->selectPageRows();

        $this->selectAll = false;
        $this->selected = [];
    }

    public function selectPageRows()
    {
        $this->selected = $this->rows->pluck('id')->map(fn($id) => (string) $id);
    }

    public function selectAll()
    {
        $this->selectAll = true;
    }

    public function getSelectedRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        return (clone $this->rowsQuery)
            ->unless($this->selectAll, fn($query) => $query->whereKey($this->selected));
    }
}
```

**Context**

- Livewire version: 2.3.6
- Laravel version: 8.23.1
- Alpine version: 2.8.0
- Browser: Chrome

Comment: What does just this code returns ```$this->selectedRowsQuery->roles()```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line won't work:

```
$this->selectedRowsQuery->roles()->detach();
```

`$this->selectedRowsQuery` is a Collection, and your code isn't smart enough to know which instance of `roles()` you're trying to detach (delete). You simply need to do this in a loop:

```
foreach ($this->selectedRowsQuery as $queryRow) {
  $queryRow->roles()->detach();
  $queryRow->delete(); // Can do this here (single delete), or below
}

$this->selectedRowsQuery->delete(); // Can do this here (batch delete), or above
```

Edit: At the time of the `foreach()`, `$this->selectedRowsQuery` is still an instance of the `Builder` class, which is incompatible with `foreach()` until a Closure (`get()`, `cursor()`, etc.) is passed. To handle this, simply adjust your code as:

```
foreach ($this->selectedRowsQuery->get() as $queryRow) {
  $queryRow->roles()->detach();
  ...
}
```

Note: `->get()` is more widely used, but `->cursor()` is available and generally more performant for larger loops.

Comment: Its showing me the success notification but its not deleting the data from the table. It's not running the code within the for each loop and is directly displaying the notification. Here is the gif. [Role Detach Bulk](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/65024122/105073750-785af100-5aad-11eb-802c-48c78eae5e10.gif)

Comment: If I am taking the `$this->selectedRowsQuery->delete();` outside the loop, then its throwing me an error, i.e. Integrity constraint violation, it means the relationship is still there and the code within the foreach loop isn't running. What can be done?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see it. You might nee to add a `->get()` to your query; i.e. it's still a `Builder` instance, and `foreach()` doesn't work on it. Does it work if you do `foreach ($this->selectedRowsQuery->get() as $queryRow) { ... }`?

Comment: Yes mate, absolutely :). Thanks alot its working as it should!

Comment: Excellent, I'll update my answer to explain what's going on :) Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to ask is there a way without foreach loop? As it takes a while if we delete a huge number of data in bulk. It runs the query multiple times with this.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely an issue. You could do it with a manual query, like `DB::table('user_role')->whereIn('user_id', $this->selectedRowsQuery->pluck('id'))->delete()`, which would (should, do some testing) do a `DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3 ...);` in a single query, as opposed to each of those IDs in a loop.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :) Edit, just remembered this, might be useful for your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599520/laravel-bulk-detach (answer suggests same approach, but in slightly different words)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227557/discussion-between-toxifiedhashkey-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: Hey, please have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65798577/13399106, its similar to the above problem, your help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Yup, I saw it :) Not sure if it'll be something I can help with TBH; like I said Livewire stuff is foreign to me.

Comment: Ohh okay, my bad luck then :P. You don't have an idea about traits too? It's somehow related. It's alright if you can't you have already helped quite alot!

Comment: I'm familiar with traits and how they work, yeah, just not in the context of Liveware. Like I said, I'll help if I can; not available at the moment, hopefully someone else can in the meantime :)